# Read site html from a site in a different geo region

Tags: geolocation

I am using python and Beautiful soup to read html pages.  Unfortunately some sites redirect to my Geo region (AU) so I can't retrieve the target countries version i.e. (UK, US, FR, NZ...)

I have tried using a VPN service but this requires me to manually change the region so I can't automate the process.  I have tried using the python quartz.Coregraphics library to click the options on screen but this is temperamental.

Is there a way I can achieve this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to nut this one out myself.  Best answered by example for reading a uk based site.

```
import urllib2
url = 'Some-uk-url'

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Accept-Language', 'en-gb')
req.add_header('X-Forwarded-For', [a uk proxy ipaddress here])

htmltext = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```